# Translating a function that styles a div based on mouse movement from jQuery to Angular makes coordinates spazz out

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is a [JSFiddle of the function](https://jsfiddle.net/2Radon/w1qxp4um/) I built some time ago in JQuery before I learned AngularJS for the project I intended to use it in.

```
var numberOfPosts = 1; // To calculate the absolute/starting position of each post
var post = $('#post'); // Need to track multiple posts, ideally by array of getElementsByClass
var postOffset = post.offset(); // Relative to the document
var postPosition = post.position(); // Relative to the parent
var radiansBetweenPosts = (90 / numberOfPosts) * Math.PI / 180;

$('#wrapper').mousemove(function(event) {
  // Mouse horizontal percentage position inside the wrapper (double to make full circle)
  mouseX = (event.pageX - postOffset.left) / post.parent().width() * 2;
  x = (Math.cos(Math.PI * mouseX + radiansBetweenPosts)) * 50 + 50; // Multiply by % size of a quadrant,
  y = (Math.sin(Math.PI * mouseX + radiansBetweenPosts)) * 50 + 50; // add a % offset to the centre of the circle
  post.css({
    'left': x + '%',
    'top': y + '%'
  });
  // Mouse horizontal % coordinates from the centre of the circle
  $('p').html(Math.round(mouseX * 100));
});
```

And [here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O2OoSlK6FR2NZCzb7scS?p=preview) of the same idea I translated to AngularJS, which is how it currently behaves on my project.

```
  angular.module('mouseMovement', [])
  .controller('MouseMovementController', ['$scope', '$element', function MouseMovementController($scope, $element) {
    $scope.msg = "Mouse X position inside the div"

    numberOfPosts = 1
    radiansBetweenPosts = (90 / numberOfPosts) * Math.PI / 180

    $scope.mousePosition = function(event) {

      postOffsetLeft = event.target.querySelector('.postDiv').offsetLeft
      frameWidth = event.target.offsetWidth
      mouseXpercent = (event.pageX - postOffsetLeft) / frameWidth * 2

      x = (Math.cos(Math.PI * mouseXpercent + radiansBetweenPosts)) * 50 + 50
      y = (Math.sin(Math.PI * mouseXpercent + radiansBetweenPosts)) * 50 + 50

      $scope.position = {
        left: x + '%',
        top: y + '%'
      }

      $scope.mouseX = Math.round(mouseXpercent * 100)
      $scope.postX = Math.round(x)
      $scope.postY = Math.round(y)

    }
  }])
```

It appears to me that when the mouse is moved across the div, the coordinates jump between a single digit and a two or three digit number very quickly, which you can observe if you move the mouse for a bit and check the numbers a few times. That I believe is what causes the position to spazz out like that.

Oddly, that only happens when the $scope.position variable is there, so if you comment that bit out, both the Post X and Post Y numbers will steadily change as they should when you move your mouse across the div.

What am I missing here? It seems like the coordinate calculation is suddenly wrong when the styles are applied, but that can't be true. To make it more weird, at some sedctions of the div the numbers are steadily and correctly changing, for example verticall under this bolded word on the Plunker "Mouse X position inside **the** div"
If it's something in the way AngularJS works internally, what solutions are there?

In addition to that, I'll need to somehow keep tracking the mouse movement across the gray div even if the mouse appears on top of the

Comment: Any reason you're never getting the y position of the mouse?

Comment: Yes, I only want to make the post element move in a circle based on the horizontal position of the mouse. The vertical position will not be used or used for something else.

Answer (score 2):

Your math is off. Try [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/wjH6uAqNa098SMI1mnTL?p=preview). My math isn't exact but it's closer to what you're looking for

```
angular.module('mouseMovement', [])
  .controller('MouseMovementController', ['$scope', '$element',     function MouseMovementController($scope, $element) {
$scope.msg = "Mouse X position inside the div"

numberOfPosts = 1
radiansBetweenPosts = (2 / numberOfPosts) * Math.PI

$scope.mousePosition = function(event) {

  postOffsetLeft = event.target.querySelector('.postDiv').offsetLeft
  frameWidth = event.target.offsetWidth
  mouseXpercent = (event.pageX) / frameWidth 

  x = Math.PI * (Math.cos(mouseXpercent * radiansBetweenPosts)) * 10 + 40
  y = Math.PI * (Math.sin(mouseXpercent * radiansBetweenPosts)) * 10 + 20

  $scope.position = {
    left: x + '%',
    top: y + '%'
  }

  $scope.mouseX = Math.round(mouseXpercent * 100)
  $scope.postX = Math.round(x)
  $scope.postY = Math.round(y)

}
}])
```

Comment: That's cool, but how come the same math I had worked perfectly in jQuery?
And it's the key thing to get that circle to fit perfectly within the div, just like in the jQuery example, and so far I haven't found  the solution for that in your calculation.

Comment: I've come back to trying to solve this and it seems that in your solution I can no longer change the number of posts. I don't really understand what you did with the variable radiansBetweenPosts, but it is supposed to offset the moving post so that if any more are added they space out and don't stack up. So whatever number it makes in your equation is a number that's needed in the calculation anyway...

Comment: Still got no clue why it spazzes out on the correct equation.